# Delegate methods are not called when the class that is implements them is instantiated

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

My parser uses MWFeedParserDelegate delagate which calls the doneParsingObjects perfectly fine

```
@interface Parser ()<MWFeedParserDelegate> 
...
-(void) doneParsingObjects{
      NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Now if in a different class, I allocate the parser, my delegate method doneParsingObjects never gets called.

```
Parser * newsParser = [[Parser alloc]init];
```

I know I can add the delegate to a different class but would like to know why when I initiate a parser object & that implements a delegate, the delegate methods do not get triggered.

---

```
/* my View Controller */
@implementation getSourceAndTopicViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Parser * newsParser = [[Parser alloc]init];
    newsParser.dataSource = self;
    NSURL * feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://news.yahoo.com/rss/"];
    [newsParser parseURL:feedURL];
}
/* this method never gets called. Don't know why */
-(void) Parser:(parserViewController *)parser doneParsingObjects:(NSMutableArray *)parsedItems{
    NSLog(@"Method was called");
}
_______________________________________
/* Parser.h Class */
@class Parser;
@protocol ParserDataSource
   -(void) Parser:(Parser *)parser doneParsingObjects:(NSMutableArray *)parsedItems;
@end
@interface Parser : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak)id <ParserDataSource > dataSource;
/* Parser.m 
I'd like to call my own datasource method in the viewController once MWFeedParser calls back feedParserDidFinish */
@interface Parser ()<MWFeedParserDelegate>{
    MWFeedParser *feedParser;
}
...
@end
@implementation Parser
...
/* This method is supposed to be called by the MWFeedParserDelegate but never gets triggered from my view controller when I instantiate newParser */
- (void)feedParserDidFinish:(MWFeedParser *)parser {
        NSLog(@"%@", self.MWFeedItems);
    [self.dataSource Parser:self doneParsingObjects:self.parsedItems; 
}
```

I know this problem would be solved if I use the MWFeedParserDelegate in my view controller but I would like to have the parser be the one dealing with MWFeedParserDelegate.

Comment: Please explain what did you expect to happen, and when did you expect it to happen.

Comment: Are you setting your delegate? `newsParser.delegate = self;`

Comment: Please see below. I want that method to be get the following output "Method was called" from my viewController without having to include the MWFeedParser delegate in my view-controller.

Comment: because you have to tell your object WHO is your delegate. delegates are used to inform other classes. add what the other oscar asked u to add.

Answer (score 1):

Merely creating an object doesn't call the delegate methods.  The object is intended to be supplied to another object that makes use of the delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that My parser was going out of scope because it was defined locally. Defining a delegate that relies on other delegates works perfectly. You just need to make sure the objects that implement the delegate our defined as properties. Very tricky.

Thanks everyone for the replies.